# Angular switch opacity based on value

Tags: javascript, css, angular

So I have these two flags:

[image]

```
<div class="flag flag-srb" id="2" (click)="changeLanguage(2)">
    <img src="assets/flags/srb.png" alt="srb" height="64" width="64">
</div>
<div class="flag flag-eng" id="1" (click)="changeLanguage(1)">
    <img src="assets/flags/eng.png" alt="eng" height="64" width="64">
</div>
```

By default the opacity is 0.5 in both of these. The css:

```
.flag {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Now I want to change the opacity to 1 depeding on the one the user has selected. Then when he switches to a different flag (clicks  on a different flag) the opacity changes to 1 for the one he selected and reverts to 0.5 the other one.

When he clicks the flag he activates this function:

```
 changeLanguage(id){
    this.sightService.changeLanguageId(id);
    this.sightService.getSights().subscribe(sights => {
      this.sights = sights;
    });

    console.log("this.sights is now: ", this.sights);
    console.log("id is",id);

    var testNula = document.getElementById(id); //GET PICTURE WITH ID
    var testDva = document.getElementById(id).id; //GET PICTURE ID, THE NUMBER

    if(testDva == this.sights[0].pin_lang_id) { //WHAT I TRIED
      console.log("THIS ONE IS SELECTED", testDva);
      testNula.style.opacity = "1";
    } else if (testDva != this.sights[0].pin_lang_id) {
      testNula.style.opacity = "0.5";
    }
  }
```

Note that `this.sights[0].pin_lang_id` is loaded with a service. So that changes when he clicks the flag. I wanted to change the opacity using this.

Also, when the page loads the `this.sights[0].pin_lang_id` is 2, so the first flag should be opacity 1, the other 0.5. When he clicks the English flag, the first flag should be 0.5 while the English 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the .ts create a new variable `selectedLang`
in the `changeLanguageId` update the variable based on the index

```
 changeLanguage(id){
    this.sightService.changeLanguageId(id);
    this.sightService.getSights().subscribe(sights => {
      this.sights = sights;
    });
    this.selectedLang = id;
  }
```

```
<div class="flag flag-srb" id="2" [style.opacity]="{{this.selectedLang === 2 ? 1 : 0.5}}" (click)="changeLanguage(2)">
    <img src="assets/flags/srb.png" alt="srb" height="64" width="64">
</div>
<div class="flag flag-eng" id="1" [style.opacity]="{{this.selectedLang === 1 ? 1 : 0.5}}" (click)="changeLanguage(1)">
    <img src="assets/flags/eng.png" alt="eng" height="64" width="64">
</div>
```

Comment: I can't load the page. I get an error `Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("changeLanguage(1)">
        <img src="assets/flags/eng.png" alt="eng" height="64" width="64">
    [ERROR ->]</div>` Probably because of [style.opacity] in the html

Comment: Works actually if you don't put curly braces, but just regular " "

Answer (score 0):

You can set a  variable as selected flag index

```
var selectedflag
```

index;

Then as per the service gives you the index set the flags value

```
this.selectflagindex =this.sights[0].pin_lang_id;
```

Then in the template compare the selected index and set the opacity to 1 but by default set it to 0.5 for all

You div goes like this

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'opacity':check selected(id)}" </div>


checkselected(id){ return this.selectedFlag == id ? '1' :'0.5'}
```

By sending appropriate id the value of opacity will be set for the div.

This will do for any amount of language not only for two